# the attribute "href" of a <a> tag is a URL,but it calls functions after clicking the <a> tag.How it works

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

I found this question in jQuery UI demos.If you downloaded the jQuery UI,and so it located in "demos/droppable/photo-manager.html".

In this html page,there were several  tags showing the delete icons in photo div.These  tags' property named "href" are URLs,but it would call functions after clicking the  tags.
URLs->functions?How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a click event to a link and null the browser's default behaviour.

#### HTML

```
<a href="http://example.com">Example</a>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   func();
});
```

Comment: And for further further investigation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: Your suggestion is good,but the application of i said is not accomplished by your advice.I want to know how jQuery ui make a <a> tag's href instanced by URL clicked to call several functions in differnt js files.Thank you a lot.