# jQuery initiate JavaScript action

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

```
<div class="button">                     
    <a class="testclass" href="javascript:actionx(objectId);"></a>
</div>
```

So the question is how do I initiate JavaScript bit using jQuery, I have tried:

```
window.location = javascript:actionx(objectId);
```

And some other similar variations, but they do not seem to work.

By the way, class is universal and all the buttons have it. The only thing that changes is the `objectId`.

Comment: what exactly is this `objectId` , is it suppose to be some id or something else.add more information about your question.

Comment: you could think of it as an Id of an object in a database, but basically its like (29485) sequence of numbers. when the page loads it's not actually a variable but a number ( not ObjectId but 29540)

Comment: What is expected result ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817422/the-attribute-href-of-a-a-tag-is-a-url-but-it-calls-functions-after-clicking/7817435#7817435

Comment: add mentioned object into a list basically

Comment: Post a sample out put you're expecting as your JS no way near to what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to redirect then you can try this:

**html:**

```
<div class="button">                     
<a class="testclass" href=" javascript:actionx(1234);">Redirect</a>
</div>
```

**script:**

```
function actionx(data){
    //rest of the code without return
    window.location="d3.php";//here your location to redirect
}
```